# jquery draggable div stays enabled after mouse leaves iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable

Here is a demo of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Sb9ku/3/

The demo has three boxes.

The blue box is a jquery draggable div with containment set to "body".

The red box is the body.

The black box is an iframe.  The src points to an html page with the red and blue box. (http://jsfiddle.net/nHA9k/3/)

Here's how to reproduce the problem.

First, open firefox.

1. Drag the blue box to the right.  Don't release the drag until your mouse position is outside the iframe (black box).  Once your mouse is outside the black box, release.
2. Move your mouse back into the red box.  Notice that the blue box is not dragging.
3. Now repeat steps 1 and 2, but release your mouse within the iframe, but outside the red box.

Now, open IE9 and repeat steps 1, 2, and 3.
You'll notice that dragging is still enabled when the mouse release happens outside the iframe.  When dragging is released inside the iframe, but outside the body (red box) then dragging is stopped.

Does anybody know how one would fix this odd behavior in IE9?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution for this?